# Hold'em Manager: Why resets HUD my stats on each table switch?

Tags: holdem-manager

When I play MTT and have my tracking tool running with HUD it resets always the stats in the HUD as soon as I switch the table.

Is this necessary or is there somewhere an option, that I didn't find yet, where I can see the overall stats of villians and hero (myself) in the HUD?

Comment: Which pokersite is this on? Holdemmanager tends to work a lot better on the bigger sites like Pokerstars and Full Tilt. Whereas i know on PKR it doesnt work well at all and does what you are saying above.

Comment: I'm on pokerstars. And I think the software runs well. But only the HUD resets it's data as soon as I switch table in a MTT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official website that is by design

See the following link:

[Hud stats reset on table change](http://forums.holdemmanager.com/general-support/186021-hud-stats-reset-table-change.html)

Although I am pretty sure mine don't will check tonight when im playing.

Comment: I found an option in HUD options on table, where you can switch between table and all date. I'll provide a screenshot this evening.

Answer (score 0):

Holdem Manager show your stats based on only current tournament.

This is because there are multiple types of games: limit/no-limit, deepstack, turbos; for which you would play differently, hence it show stats only for 1 (current) MTT. The same holds for your opponents.

Comment: Yes, but when I'm in a MTT and our table gets closed and I move to a new table, all my stats in HUD get reset. So it looks like HUD stats are only for one table.

Answer (score -1):

It's so you know what your stats look like to the other players at the table. This is especially useful in MTT's as the chance of you playing the same players over multiple tables is greatly diminished compared to cashgames.

Comment: But when I am final table, I should look in holdemmanager if I've already any data about my opponents? Because there is no chance to get this data on HUD?